# Invalidate(true) makes no output,why?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

these codes are the WM_CHAR handler,  but outputs nothing when type some words??

```
void CMy3456View::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
{

Invalidate(true);
//MessageBox(L"dfs");//enable this line,then the  outputs turns normal,why???
CClientDC dc(this);

CString c=L"";
c.Format(L"%c",nChar);
dc.TextOutW(0,0,c);

CView::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be painting in the window inside OnChar, you should let your WM_PAINT handler process it. `Invalidate` causes a WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT to follow soon after, which is probably erasing the results of your TextOutW.

Comment: The MessageBox function includes a message processing loop, so the WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT wind up being called before you call TextOutW instead of afterwards.

Comment: @Harry Johnston:Calling the MessageBox() function will create a new window, and have it's own loop for handling messages. Messages of the message box are handled inside this loop, and does this have something to do with  WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT caused by `Invalidate`???

Comment: MessageBox has to dispatch all window messages sent to the current thread, not just those for the message box itself.  Otherwise, the other windows associated with the thread would hang until the message box was dismissed.